# Warning: mysqli_stmt::close(): Couldn't fetch mysqli_stmt in X on line Y

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm pretty new to php coding and managed to resolve a lot of problems myself, but there is 1 I can't get my head around.

```
$prep_stmt = "SELECT id FROM members WHERE Email = ? LIMIT 1";
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($prep_stmt);

// check existing Email
if ($stmt) {
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $Email);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->store_result();

    if ($stmt->num_rows == 1) {
        // A user with this Email address already exists
        $error_msg .= '<p class="error">A user with this Email address already exists.</p>';
        $stmt->close();
    }
            $stmt->close();
} else {
    $error_msg .= '<p class="error">Database error Line 39</p>';
            $stmt->close();
}
```

My guess is that the code can't get to the 2nd `$stmt->close();` in the above code (the one after the if inside the if).

How can I resolve this problem? Is that `$stmt->close();` really needed?

Comment: Well you could wrap that one in an `else {}` block, but honestly, none of the explicit calls to `$stmt->close()` are likely to be necessary. PHP will clean them up itself.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski, so it's safe to remove all of them? (Post an answer please so I can give some rep :) )

Comment: Probably.  If there are rows to be fetched, [calling `$stmt->close()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.close.php) frees the RDBMS to execute a new query, but if you aren't going to issue a new query  in this script that isn't a problem because PHP will clean them up on script termination. Plus, if I recall correctly, calling `store_result()` sidesteps that problem anyway.

Comment: In particular, the last `$stmt->close()` in the DB error block will never successfully execute  because $stmt won't be an object. Definitely remove that one because it will cause a fatal error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why you don't just remove the first one (in the second if statement)? Also remove the `close()` in your `else` statement because you checked if `$stmt` is a legal object. Basically what you say is: `$stmt` isn't a legal object, close it. But close what?

This will work in both situations:

```
$prep_stmt = "SELECT id FROM members WHERE Email = ? LIMIT 1";
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($prep_stmt);

// check existing Email
if ($stmt) {
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $Email);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->store_result();

    if ($stmt->num_rows == 1) {
        // A user with this Email address already exists
        $error_msg .= '<p class="error">A user with this Email address already exists.</p>';
        //Remove this one: $stmt->close();
    }
    $stmt->close();
} else {
    $error_msg .= '<p class="error">Database error Line 39</p>';
    //This one can be removed because $stmt isn't a legal object: $stmt->close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the `if` statements and the `close()` method calls. Why have you added that to your code?

Th reason why you are getting this error is because you try to close a statement **when its creation failed.** You can't close an object which was never created. If `prepare()` call fails and you have your error reporting silenced this function will return `false` instead of an object.

If you enable proper error reporting there should be no `if` statements. See [How to get the error message in MySQLi?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22662582/1839439)

Here is how your code should look like:

```
$prep_stmt = "SELECT id FROM members WHERE Email = ? LIMIT 1";
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($prep_stmt);

// check existing Email
$stmt->bind_param('s', $Email);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();

if ($result->fetch_assoc()) {
    // A user with this Email address already exists
    $error_msg .= '<p class="error">A user with this Email address already exists.</p>';
}
```

Try to avoid `store_result()` as much as possible. When you enable error reporting then there's no reason for any `if` statements. Otherwise, you would need to wrap each line in such statement, because any of these calls could fail: `prepare()`, `bind_param()`, `execute()`, ...

There's no need to close the statement if you fetch all the results. When you call `get_result()` you fetch everything from MySQL.

Keep it simple and don't add unnecessary code.

Answer (score -1):

You should put `store_result()` after execute like bellow:

```
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();
```

if you make a method and pass query, it doesn't work